# Ни зависит ни от формы, ни от массы

Tags: орфография

Ускорение свободного падения **ни** зависит ни от массы, ни от формы падающего тела.(Учебник физики)
 Почему "ни зависит", а не "не зависит"?

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае нужно отрицание "не". В учебнике допущена ошибка.

Comment: Да, типичная отрицательная конструкция: Частица НЕ перед глаголом выражает отрицание, а сочинительный соединительный союз НИ...НИ, связывающий однородные члены, имеет усилительное значение.